# TensorFlow 2.0 clip_by_value change parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

Hello I have an model that uses the `tf.clip_by_value` method: [Documentation tf.clip_by_value](http://tensorflow.biotecan.com/python/Python_1.8/tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value.html)

After training I would like to change the clipping parameters. But this seems to be not possible:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
tf_op_layer_clip_by_value_4/Min [(None, 1)]          0           x[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_clip_by_value_5/Min [(None, 1)]          0           y[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_clip_by_value_4 (Te [(None, 1)]          0           tf_op_layer_clip_by_value_4/Minim
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_clip_by_value_5 (Te [(None, 1)]          0           tf_op_layer_clip_by_value_5/Minim
```

Is there a way to access and change the parameter of the clipping layer within a model?

Comment: The column `Param #` is not the parameter given to the layer, but the number of trainable parameters within the layer. A value clipping layer does not have any trainable parameter. If you have an existing model with this layer, I do not think it would be possible to change the clipping value, though. If you have some code that builds that model, you should be able to edit it to adjust the clipping value.

Comment: After trying a few things I found this solution:

To access and change the parameters of a `tf.clip_by_value` layer in your model you can access them in the following way:     `model.layers[N].constants[1] = clip_value_max`, and `model.layers[N+1].constants[1] = clip_value_min`

After modification you have to compile your model. If you trained your model before, the weights will be preserved. The last thing that is missing is a convenient way to find which two layers perform the clipping.